# For a file, how do I go back to a previous version in Git?

Tags: git

For my current file, I want to "go back" to version __.  How do I do that in Git?

I don't want the version to be my newest head. I just want to see what code was there at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to overwrite the version in your working tree, then use `git show`:

```
git show rev:path/to/file
```

The `rev` is usually any expression (see the Specifying Revisions section in [*git-rev-parse(1)*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html)) that can be resolved into a commit<sup>1</sup>.
The `path/to/file` should be the path of the file of interest (starting from the top level of the repository).

For example, show `src/config.c` from the “fix bugs” commit:

```
% git log --oneline
7c07566 second feature
bbdbea8 fix bugs
1cf42c8 first feature
82cfa1d initial commit
% git show bbdbea8:src/config.c
```

`bbdbea8` could also have been the full object name (`bbdbea801c2a465a8c509befa46174bad4fd9fd4` in my test repository), or the expression `HEAD~` or `HEAD^` (if you already knew that the commit you were interested in was the first parent of the current HEAD).

<sup>1</sup>
In the `rev:path` syntax, `rev` does not have to be a “commit-ish”, it can be any “treeish” (and the path starts from the specified tree instead of the top-level).

---

Git can also compare different versions of files without having to explicitly extract each file:

Show the cumulative changes made to `src/config.c` since bbdbea8:

```
git diff bbdbea8 -- src/config.c
```

Or, sometimes it is useful to review the history bit by bit. Show each change to `src/config.c` since bbdbea8:

```
git log -p --reverse bbdbea8.. -- src/config.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following which just checks out the particular version of the file

```
git checkout revision -- filename
```

Comment: When I did git log, it does not show the revision #.


commit 36d5813f749d2bff5764d372ebca5f57ea21a16b
Date:   Mon Mar 28 22:32:44 2011 -0700

    after splitting views

Comment: Then use git checkout 36d5813f749d2bff5764d372ebca5f57ea21a16b --filename